# SVN repo with external trunk

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have read-only access to the trunk of a SVN repository and I want to create another SVN repository in which the trunk is taken from the previous repository.

I tried using the "externals" tag, but when I clone the trunk to create a new branch I get an error saying that I cannot perform a copy between different repositories.

Is there another way to do it? The first repo is https://svn.bigr.nl/elastix/trunkpublic
both user and password are "elastixguest".

Comment: Do you require revision history to be included in the new repo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using svnsnyc? One advantage is you don't need to have admin access to the old repository. You just need to execute two commands:

init: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.init.html

sync: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.sync.html